# The usage of "appear"

Tags: word-usage

Dictionary says "appear" is not used in the progressive tenses when means "to give the impression of being or doing sth."

Does this also apply to the meaning " to start to be seen"? For example, can I use the progressive tense of it in the following sentence?

> An increasing number of professors are **appearing** in television news programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For meanings related to 'perform', you can use `appear` in progressive forms. Your sentence qualifies and so it is correct. Other examples:

> She will be **appearing** in the new series of Game of Thrones.

> That actor has been **appearing** in a lot of romance movies in recent years.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appear